# Run wsgi with apache and django in anaconda environment

Tags: python, django, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a django application with wsgi_mod and apache2. But for some strange reason it cannot import django.

```
# /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
WSGIDaemonProcess django_apps python-home=/home/swacker/miniconda3/envs/django/
WSGIProcessGroup django_apps
WSGIScriptAlias /koala /var/www/production/Koala/Koala/wsgi.py process-group=django_apps

<Directory /var/www/production/Koala/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>
```

The application sits in /var/www/production/Koala.
My conda enviromnent is installed in /home/user/miniconda3/envs/django.
I installed wsgi inside the conda environment.

I tried different things, but nothing worked. This is what I did to get wsgi running.

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
pip install mod_wsgi
conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/travis uwsgi
```

It looks like wsgi is just not working with conda environments and I have to use virtualenv?? Wsgi works, I can render a test file just fine.

Though, when I go to `localhost/koala` the `/var/log/apache2/error.log` shows:

> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>    ImportError: No module named 'django'

I searched a lot, but could not find an answer that addresses this properly.

Comment: You should not be installing system mod_wsgi package. Use ``pip`` method only. See correct way to configure existing Apache to use ``pip`` installed version in https://pypi.org/project/mod_wsgi/ You also don't need uwsgi, that is something different again.

Comment: So Apache is actually not needed? I find the documentations are not very clear.

Comment: I can use it but the page looks pretty broken.

Comment: You don't need ``libapache2-mod-wsgi`` but you still need the Apache package itself. If you have it running and have separate issue, create a new question.

Comment: I leave this question open though. It is still not answered. Running the wsgi stuff with apache is the first way mentioned in the django manual, so I am sure other people are running into this as well.